# Migrating a wordpress site from azure sql to Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I need to migrate a mysql db including data from ms azure to my regular hosting provider. I already have an empty db waiting there.

The db contains a wordpress+woocommerce and various plugin tables.

Plz help..

Everywhere i find migrating from Mysql to sql but not Sql to Mysql

Comment: Have you tried simply assuming that the Azure database is completely compatible with MySQL?

Comment: Yes i have observed and i also got the solution..thanx alot..

Answer (score 1):

You should try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) which can easily do a migration from SQL Server (and Azure DB) to MySQL. The migration can be on the fly or it can result in some .sql scripts that you have to load in you MySQL database using your regular client (phpMyAdmin, EMMA or of course, MySQL Workbench).

You can find additional information about the migration capabilities of MySQL Workbench [here](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/).